# how to make 2 pictures from 2 different cameras have the same brightness and look like one image using cv2 python

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, image-stitching, panoramas

I have 2 cameras that taking pictures in 40 fps,
I want to concat them together and have them continue each other like the picture comes from one camera.[image]

[image]

any ideas on how I should approach this?

EDIT:

i used a software to show how roughly i merge the images and the color difference that rises from the merges:
(its to big so i upload it to a site)
https://ibb.co/8xx0BWC

EDIT2:
I already tried this post that seems to answer my problem, it didn't work as expected:
[color match in images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56918877/color-match-in-images)

Comment: Do you mean you want to make a single image that’s like a panorama?

Comment: yes, when I create the panorama picture and get the rgb the left picture is darker then the right picture, I'll edit the question and add the picture.

Comment: See https://pyimagesearch.com/2014/06/30/super-fast-color-transfer-images/